# Java convert minutes into hours minutes

Tags: java

I need to convert minutes to hours and minutes in java, so i do this 
***java:***

```
long minutes = offer.getDuration();
long hours = minutes / 60;
long minnutesRemaining = minutes % 60;
trainOffer.setDuration(hours+"h"+minnutesRemaining);
```

***output:***

```
minutes = 129
hours = 2
minnutesRemaining = 9
```

how can i do for have `minnutesRemaining = 09` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.format to format the output:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02d", minnutesRemaining ));
```